# ¿cómo exportar a excel una tabla html usando PHPExcel?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

bueno he intentado exportar a excel con el uso de esta libreria pero no me funciona. que estoy haciendo mal?

```
<?php 
/*********************************************************************
    ws_exportExcel_rs.php

    Servicio php que exporta archivos a Excel

******************************************************************* */

if (isset($_POST['datos_a_enviar'])) {
    set_time_limit(0);

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');//Definimos la zona horaria del servidor

    // Load the table view into a variable
    $html = $this->load->view('table_view', $_POST['datos_a_enviar'], true);

    // Put the html into a temporary file
    $tmpfile = time().'.html';
    file_put_contents($tmpfile, $html);

    // Read the contents of the file into PHPExcel Reader class
    $reader = new PHPExcel_Reader_HTML; 
    $content = $reader->load($tmpfile); 

    // Pass to writer and output as needed
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($content, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('excelfile.xlsx');

    // Delete temporary file
    unlink($tmpfile);

}else {
    header("Location: ../../../index.php");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bueno al final lo logre de la siguiente forma:

```
if (isset($_POST['datos_a_enviar']) && strlen($_POST['datos_a_enviar']) > 0) {

    // Create your database query
    $query = $_POST['datos_a_enviar'];  

    // Execute the database query
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());


    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    // Add some data
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Campo1');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'Campo2');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Campo3');
    ...

    $rowCount = 2; //new

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row[0]); 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row[4]); 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $row[1]); 
        ...

        // Increment the Excel row counter
        $rowCount++; 
    }

    // Rename worksheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Excel');


    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Export_Excel_'.date('Y-m-d').'.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

    // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
    header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;

}else {
    header("Location: ../../../index.php");
}
```

Lo que hice fue pasarle el query con el que llenaba la tabla en el html y ejecute la consulta y con el resultado directamente cree la hoja de calculo en excel como se ve en el codigo y perfecto!. En caso de que alguien lo necesite aqui se lo dejo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

yo te recomendaria hacerlo de la siguiente forma

```
 <?php
    ini_set('memory_limit','3000M');
    set_time_limit(3000);

// CABECERA DEL ARCHIVO DE EXCEL
      $header = "Registro;Codigo;Usos;Evento;Fecha Vencimiento;Usuario Creacion";


        header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=NOMBRE_ARCHIVO.csv");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");

    // AGREGO LOS CAMPOS A LA TABLA DE EXCEL
        if($res)
        {
          echo $header."\n";
          while (!$res->EOF)
          {
            # code...
             echo $res->fields['id'].";"
             .$res->fields['codigo'].";"
             .$res->fields['usos'].";"
             .$res->fields['evento'].";"
             .$res->fields['fecha_limite'].";"
             .$res->fields['usuario'].";"
             ."\n";
            $res->MoveNext();
          }
        }

        $BD->desconectar();

     ?>
```

esta forma es mas comoda y manejable

Comment: de esta forma no me crea un archivo "nativo" de excel. eso lo que hace es que toma el html y lo guarda con la extencion csv

Answer (score 0):

yo te recomiendo entrar a esta repositorio y ahi esta un muy buen ejemplo de como hacer el PHPExcel

https://github.com/fgutier/PHPExcel-Examples